# How can I insert a XML file into a php or html file?

Tags: php, html, xml

Ok so if I create a XML file and than is it possible to insert the xml data into a php or html page? Thanks for the help I'm still trying to learn.

Comment: Of course, in several different ways. This is way to generic to answer.

Comment: Is it just a call what are you looking for? If so, just try to use php file_get_contents() function -> file() and so on.. take a look at php's website!

Answer (score 0):

Of course it is. You have to create a `DOMDocument object` and then parse the XML. More documentarion here: 
http://php.net/manual/es/class.domdocument.php

Comment: Not real sure what this answer has to do with XML.

Comment: I have seen people parse XML with this. It loads the XML file and then you use DOM-like functions to work with it. (getElementById, etc.)